# Open Source .NET embedded web/http server

Tags: c#, httpserver

I am working on a project where I need to embed a web server into my C# application so the application could display it's status via HTTP.  I suppose I'll want to configure it through the http also.

I am looking for an open-source library written in C# and with a licensing scheme that will allow me to link it into my existing closed source code (LGPL). Any suggestions of specific products or where to look first?

It would be great if that product could have some kind of scripting, at least templates.  All html output would go from the application, only resources would be stored on the disk (images, icons, ...)

EDIT:

I would like it to run under .NET 2.0, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Microsoft Cassini](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx), a simple HTTP server written in C# licensed under Ms-PL. It's basically a demo how to host the ASP.NET runtime.

Comment: An older version for .NET 2.0 is available here: http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2006/03/09/cassini-update.aspx It's probably a better idea to backport the most recent version to .NET 2.0 though.

Comment: Cassini is also the test server used when debugging ASP.NET apps in Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, I have known issues with .net > 2.0 :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359974/convince-me-to-move-to-net-3-5-from-2-0